# Ruby adding empty strings to hash for CSV spacing

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I have:

```
hash = {"1"=>["A", "B", "C", ... "Z"], "2"=>["B", "C"], "3"=>["A", "C"]
```

My goal is to use `hash` as a source for creating a CSV with columns whose names are a letter of the alphabet and with rows `hash(key)` = 1,2,3 etc.

I created an array of all `hash.values.unshift("")`values that serve as row 1 (columns labels).

desired output:

```
 | A | B | C | ... | Z |
1| A | B | C | ... | Z |
2|   | B | C | ....... |
3| A |   | C | ....... |
```

Creating CSV:

```
CSV.open("groups.csv", 'w') do |csv|
  csv << row1
  hash.each do |v|
    csv << v.flatten
  end
end
```

This makes the CSV look almost what I want but There is no spacing to get columns to align.

Any advice on how to make a method for modifying my hash that compares my all [A-Z] against each subsequent hash key (rows) to insert empty strings to provide spacing?

Can Class CSV do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
require 'csv'
ALPHA = ('A'..'Z').to_a.freeze
hash={"1"=>ALPHA, "2"=>["B", "C"], "3"=>["A", "C"]}

csv = CSV.generate("", col_sep: "|") do |csv|
  csv << [" "] + ALPHA # header
  hash.each do |k, v|
    alphabet = ALPHA.map { |el| [el, 0] }.to_h
    v.each { |el| alphabet[el] += 1 }

    csv << [k, *alphabet.map { |k, val| val == 1 ? k : " " }]
  end
end

csv.split("\n").each { |row| puts row }
```

output:

```
 |A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z
1|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z
2| |B|C| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
3|A| |C| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Comment: Anthony, I'm looking for CSV output of row '2' to be 2 |  | B | C |   so only A's can be in column (A)

Answer (score 0):

If your values are truly single characters and don't need the CSV escaping, then I recommend bypassing CSV altogether and building the string in plain Ruby.

Assuming you want to align your lines correctly regardless of the number of digits in the row number (e.g. 1, 10, and 100), you can use printf style formatting to guarantee horizontal aligment (assuming your row number width never exceeds the value of `ROWNUM_WIDTH`).

By the way, I changed the hash's keys to integers, hope that's ok.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

FIELDS = ('A'..'Z').to_a
DATA = { 1 => FIELDS, 2 => %w(B C), 3 => %w(A C) }
ROWNUM_WIDTH = 3

output = ' ' * ROWNUM_WIDTH + " | #{FIELDS.join(' | ')} |\n"

DATA.each do |rownum, values|
  line = "%*d | " % [ROWNUM_WIDTH, rownum]
  FIELDS.each do |field|
    char = values.include?(field) ? field : ' '
    line << "#{char} | "
  end
  output << line << "\n"
end

puts output

=begin
Outputs:

    | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
  1 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
  2 |   | B | C |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  3 | A |   | C |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |

=end
```

Comment: I was slightly obfuscating my goal. In my real problem I'm working with usernames that are all in alphabetically sorted. 1, ,2 ,3 are groupnames.

Comment: I see. Anyway, you can either set `ROWNUM_WIDTH` to a reasonable maximum width, or you could do something like `ROWNUM_WIDTH = DATA.keys.map(&:length).max + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
all = [*?A..?Z]
hash = {"1"=>[*?A..?Z], "2"=>["B", "C"], "3"=>["A", "C"]}

hash.map do |k, v|
  [k, *all.map { |k| v.include?(k) ? k : ' ' }]
end.unshift([' ', *all]).
  map { |row| row.join('|') }
#⇒ [
#   [0] " |A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z",
#   [1] "1|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z",
#   [2] "2| |B|C| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ",
#   [3] "3|A| |C| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | "
# ]
```